# Sorting array according to the values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 229
        [val] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 237
        [val] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 238
        [val] => 6
    )
```

I need to sort this array according to the val values in the array, and do not know how to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["val"] == $b["val"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["val"] < $b["val"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($yourarray, "cmp");
```

Read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for more information.

Comment: I would do:

    uasort($yourarray, 'cmp');

to maintain keyvalue-pair (index association).

Answer (score 2):

[array_multisort](http://www.php.net/array_multisort) can help with this, example 3 presents a similar problem and solution.

Answer (score 0):

This would help - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=341245&seqNum=7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_multisort()`

Examples here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

The **Example #3 Sorting database results** is what you want. Might be easier if you are not familiar with callback functions and `usort()`.

Answer (score -1):

## use this function to sort array accroding to your need

```
function sksort(&$array, $subkey="id",$sort_ascending=false)
{
    if (count($array))
        $temp_array[key($array)] = array_shift($array);

    foreach($array as $key => $val){
        $offset = 0;
        $found = false;
        foreach($temp_array as $tmp_key => $tmp_val)
        {
            if(!$found and strtolower($val[$subkey]) > strtolower($tmp_val[$subkey]))
            {
                $temp_array = array_merge(
                    (array)array_slice($temp_array,0,$offset),
                    array($key => $val),
                    array_slice($temp_array,$offset)
                );
                $found = true;
            }
            $offset++;
        }
        if(!$found) $temp_array = array_merge($temp_array, array($key => $val));
    }

    if ($sort_ascending) $array = array_reverse($temp_array);

    else $array = $temp_array;
}
```

==========================================================================
now use this function in ur array

```
sksort($arrayname, "val"); /* for ascending */

sksort($arrayname, "val", true); /* for descending */
```